# AES encryption to decryption not outputting correctly

Tags: c++, c, encryption, arduino, arduino-esp8266

Hey all I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to go about the order of decryption the encrypted text.

This is my sketch code:

```
#include "AES.h"
#include "base64.h"

AES aes;

void gen_iv(byte  *iv) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N_BLOCK ; i++ ) {
        iv[i]= (byte) *(volatile uint8_t *)0x3FF20E44;
    }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("\nBooting...");  

    char b64data[2000];
    byte cipher[1000];
    byte iv [N_BLOCK];
    char *encodedFinal;

    Serial.println("Let's encrypt:");

    byte *key = (unsigned char*)"5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<";
    byte *my_iv = (unsigned char*)"!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV";
    char *msg = "{\"data\":{\"value\":300}, \"SEQN\":700 , \"msg\":\"IT WORKS!!\" }";

    //Set the key for AES
    aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key));

    /*
    ==================================================================
    Encoding section
    ==================================================================
    */

    //Encode IV to Base64
    base64_encode(b64data, (char *)my_iv, N_BLOCK);    
    Serial.println("      IV -> Base64: " + String(b64data));
    Serial.println("       Orignal Msg: " + String(msg));

    //Encode message into Base64
    int b64len = base64_encode(b64data, (char *)msg, String(msg).length());
    Serial.println(" Message -> Base64: " + String(b64data));

    // Encrypt into AES256   
    aes.do_aes_encrypt((byte *)b64data, b64len , cipher, key, 256, my_iv);
    Serial.println("Encrypted: " + String(b64data));

    //Encode everything now in Base64
    base64_encode(b64data, (char *)cipher, aes.get_size());
    Serial.println("Encrypted -> Base64: " + String(b64data));
    encodedFinal = (char*)b64data;
    Serial.println("Final encoded: " + String(encodedFinal));

    /*
    ==================================================================
    Decoding section
    ==================================================================
    */

Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
      Serial.println();
    //Decoding everything from Base64
    char b64dataDecode[2000];
    byte cipherDecode[1000];

    //Decode from Base64 to Encrypted msg
    base64_decode(b64dataDecode, (char *)encodedFinal, aes.get_size());
    Serial.println(" Base64 -> Encrypted: " + String(b64dataDecode));

    //Decoding from Encrypted
    aes.do_aes_decrypt((byte *)encodedFinal, base64_dec_len(encodedFinal, String(encodedFinal).length()), cipherDecode, key, 256, my_iv);
    Serial.println("Encrypted -> Original Msg: ") + String(encodedFinal);

    Serial.println("Done...");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Booting...
Let's encrypt:
      IV -> Base64: IVFBWjJXU1gjRURDNFJGVg==
       Orignal Msg: {"data":{"value":300}, "SEQN":700 , "msg":"IT WORKS!!" }
 Message -> Base64: eyJkYXRhIjp7InZhbHVlIjozMDB9LCAiU0VRTiI6NzAwICwgIm1zZyI6IklUIFdPUktTISEiIH0=
Encrypted: eyJkYXRhIjp7InZhbHVlIjozMDB9LCAiU0VRTiI6NzAwICwgIm1zZyI6IklUIFdPUktTISEiIH0=
Encrypted -> Base64: sD9f8LnxQrlOvTODLbzXPM5wWMk6+KnpmGiowTtKswGK80+yf9DyHjjiF94TwUpP/1V4f9KsHA7+1oAmBy12Dl8Dvk/ZclFvNeNrXSwCFlU=
Final encoded: sD9f8LnxQrlOvTODLbzXPM5wWMk6+KnpmGiowTtKswGK80+yf9DyHjjiF94TwUpP/1V4f9KsHA7+1oAmBy12Dl8Dvk/ZclFvNeNrXSwCFlU=




 Base64 -> Encrypted: ⸮?_⸮⸮B⸮N⸮3⸮-⸮⸮<⸮pX⸮:⸮⸮⸮h⸮⸮;J⸮⸮⸮O⸮⸮⸮8⸮⸮⸮JO⸮UxҬ⸮ր&
Encrypted -> Original Msg: 
Done...
```

As you can see above, the decryption is not working correctly. The encryption works just fine though (but i think the Encoding part is not coming out correctly since its the same as the Base64 encoding?).

Help would be great in order to solve this issue!

Comment: `aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key));` will use the size of a `byte*` as length argument. It should probably be `aes.set_key(key, strlen(key));`

Comment: and check the return values. I'm pretty sure you get FAILURE back from set_key and the functions depending on that key.

Comment: Please pick one language, either C or C++!

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt first with key and IV, and then encode to base64. On the decoder side, decode base64, and decrypt with the same key and IV.

Note that AES functions change IV, so you have to keep it a constant and copy to a mutable if you are testing in the same function.

For simplicity, remove the base64 part and just try to encrypt and decrypt:

```
int msglen = strlen(msg);
int msglen_padded = msglen  + (N_BLOCK - ((msglen - 1) % 16));
byte cipher[msglen_padded];
byte msg_decoded[msglen_padded];
byte iv[N_BLOCK];

aes.iv_inc();
aes.set_IV(my_iv);
aes.get_IV(iv);
aes.do_aes_encrypt(msg, strlen(msg) + 1, cipher, key, 256, iv);//+1 to encrypt null

aes.set_IV(my_iv);
aes.get_IV(iv);
aes.do_aes_decrypt(cipher, cipher_len, msg_decoded, key, 256, iv);

if (aes.get_size())
{
    msg_decoded[aes.get_size() - 1] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}
```

You then want to encode `cipher` to base64, and decode back to `cipher`, in between AES encrypt/decrypt

Comment: An easy, common and secure practice is to prefix the encrypted data with the IV so it will be available for decryption. The IV does need to be secret. Secrecy is provided by the key alone.

Comment: That's true @zaph Perhaps that was the asker's intention when calling `base64_encode` consecutively. I am not familiar with that base64 class, it seems the second call to `base64_encode` will just overwrite the data. Also it's not using proper key and IV, and IV should not be reused in CBC mode.